# Dirty object with named scope?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to use dirty object with named scope ?

This named_scope is working fine.

```
 named_scope :recently_tested, lambda{|test_id|
    {
      :conditions =>  ["test_id = ? and status = ?",test_id,PUBLISHED],
      :order => "updated_at DESC"
    }
  }
```

I want to enhance it. Something like

```
 named_scope :recently_tested, lambda{|test_id|
    {
      :conditions =>  ["test_id = ? and status = ? and status_was = ?",test_id,PUBLISHED,PUBLISHED],
      :order => "updated_at DESC"
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to use dirty object with named_scope ? Any other ways to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

The change helper function `status_was` isn't actually a field in your database.

Upon changing an object, `changes`, `changed?` and other helpers like your `status_was` only remain until you save the object.

If you want this to persist, you'll have to add the status_was field to your model and simply populate it in a `before_save` for example. I wouldn't call it `status_was` though, because you'd be overwriting the helper function.